# Does disabling SSID broadcasting lower a wifi antenna's total power transmission?

Tags: wireless-networking, power, ssid, antenna

Does disabling SSID broadcasting lower a wifi antenna's total power transmitted to the surrounding environment?
If yes or no , I would be glad if someone could give me any reference or measurements: metered or experience.
My goal is not any kind of security but I am searching for information about total power dissipated from the antenna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the AP still must broadcast beacons, it's just that the field of the beacon that usually contains the SSID will be omitted or zero-length. The power savings would be immeasurably small.

Comment: +1, So is total number of beacons or in my own words -idle messages - change?How much if yes (Hey man I coudln't vote up you due to low reputation Apology)

Comment: Disabling SSID broadcast does not reduce the number of packets transmitted by an idle AP. It may shrink each packet by a tiny fraction, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks a billion, you saved my time after some days of researching